# Why Jesus didn't have sins and how is it possible?

Tags: 1-corinthians, sin, peter, sinless

I'd like to understand why Jesus didn't have sins, as it states in **2 Cor 5:21**:

> 21 For our sake he made him to be sin who knew **no sin**, so that in
> him we might become the righteousness of God.

And also in **1 Pet. 2:22**:

> 22 “He committed **no sin**,
> and no deceit was found in his mouth.”

How is this possible if he was also a man living between us?

Comment: That is the mystery of the incarnation which we cannot explain.

Comment: Jesus did not inherit the sin of Adam, since he did not come of Adam. He came _of woman_ (γενομενον εκ γυναικος) Galatians 4:4. Up-voted +1.

Comment: @NigelJ unless you think that the sin nature only comes from the father (biologically?) that's not much of an explanation. Though it does lead to the Catholic doctrine of Mary's sinlessness.

Comment: This really seems like a theological synthesis question, not an exegetical question. We could leave it open and say that answers must be restricted to the context of 2 Cor and 1 Peter, but I'm not sure that there'd be too much to say. I think it would be better to close this and ask the question on [Christianity.se] (though various forms of this general question have already been asked.)

Comment: @curiousdannii The OP is asking what μη γνοντα αμαρτιαν ('knew not sin') means. I would have thought that a valid, hermeneutical question.

Answer (score 2):

Within your question is another question? How is it possible in light of the fact that Biblical Unitarians, Jehovah's Witnesses and others claim Jesus is a created being and a man like the rest of us never sinned?

Which begs the following. Romans 3:23, "For "ALL" have sinned and fall short of the glory of God." Why is not Jesus included in this clear statement? How about Romans 6:23, "For the wages of sin is death, but the free gift of God is eternal life in Christ Jesus our Lord." How come the free gift of God is through Jesus Christ who by all accounts of some, is just a man like the rest of us.

How about in the Old Testament at Jeremiah 17:9, "The heart is more deceitful than all else and desperately wicked/sick, who can know/understand it? How does the man Jesus get out of this all encompassing verse? And speaking of hearts Jesus stated this: "For from within, out of the heart of men, proceed the evil thoughts, fornications, thefts, murders, adulteries, deed of coveting and wickedness, deceit, envy, slander, pride and foolishness." Mark 7:21-22.

One more from the Old Testament, Ecclesiastes 7:20, Indeed, there is not a righteous man on earth who continually does good and who never sins." So how does the man Jesus escape this verse? In fact, Jesus ask the Jews at John 8:46, "Can any of you prove me guilty of sin? If I am telling the truth, why don't you believe Me?"

2 Corinthians 5:21 was brought up. "He/God made Him who knew no sin to be son on our behalf, that we might become the righteousness of God in Him." In other words, God treated the sinless Christ as though he were a sinner. The words of Jesus at John 3:13-15, "And no one has ascended into heaven, but He who descended from heaven, even the Son of Man. Vs14, And as Moses lifted up the serpent in the wilderness, even so must the Son of Man be lifted, vs15, that whoever believes may in Him have eternal life."

Only God can give eternal life. Notice Jesus stated, "He who descended from heaven, even the Son of Man." What did Jesus say to the Jews at John 8:56-58? "Your father Abraham rejoiced to see My day, and he saw it and was glad." How did Jesus know Abraham was "glad" unless He pre-existed? Jesus says to the Jews at John 8:58, "Before Abraham sprang into existence/born, I am."

There was an incident at Matthew 22:41-46 Jesus ask the Jews a question? Vs42, "What do you think about the Christ/Messiah, who's son is He?" They said to Him, "The Son of David. Vs43, Jesus said to them, "Then how does David in the spirit call Him Lord, saying, Vs 44, "The Lord said to My Lord, sit at my right hand until I put thine enemies beneath thy feet?"

Vs45, If David then calls Him Lord, How is He his Son?" Vs46, And no one was able to answer Him a word." So how is it that this man just happens to be the Lord of King David? It's pretty clear that how Jesus Christ didn't have any sins is because of who He is. In fact, Jesus ask His disciples that very question at Matthew 16:13-16. Vs13, "Who do people say that the Son of Man is?"

At vs16 Peter says, "Thou art the Christ, the Son of the living God." Jesus says to Peter at vs17, "Blessed are you Simon Barjona because flesh and blood did not reveal this to you, but MY Father who is in heaven." In closing, I could give a multitude of verses saying Jesus is God or why He is God, but it's the Father who does the "revealing."

Answer (score -3):

Sinless Israelites like King יוֹתָם Yotham | “Jotham” existed before Jesus the Nazarene, as documented in [2 Chronicles 27:2-6].

By maintaining faith in the commandments of YHVH, Jotham was considered Sinless - **never having to offer sacrifices to the kohanim**, as stated [II Chronicles 27.2] “He did what was proper in the eyes of the Lord, as all that his father Uzziah had done; **only he did not enter the Temple of YHVH**” (וַיַּעַשׂ הַיָּשָׁר בְּעֵינֵי יְהֹוָ֗ה כְּכֹ֚ל אֲשֶׁר־עָשָׂה עֻזִּיָּהוּ אָבִ֔יו רַק לֹא־בָא אֶל־הֵיכַל יְהֹוָה)

Jotham’s obedience to Torah (after age 25) was fully intentional - making King Yotham יוֹתָם sinless - based on [Ezekiel 18], requiring no additional Atonement by kohanim.

Comment: 'Walking blameless' (Zacharias and Elisabeth) 'blameless according to the law' (Paul the apostle) refer to an _apparent_ blamelessness in the eyes of that which can be outwardly observed. But Paul indicates a much deeper level of sin (Romans 7) that of desire within. _I had not known sin except the law hath said - thou shalt no covet_ True sinlessness is not only a perfection observed by observers, but of the depths of the heart and the mind and the will.

Comment: Most translations don't phrase that last part of the verse so positively. My Hebrew isn't good enough to know which translation is best, but it seems very plausible that the writer of Chronicles is speaking of Jotham's lack of temple attendance negatively.

Comment: What do you make of the OT scripture which says: “God looks down from heaven upon the children of men, To see if there are any who understand, who seek God. Every one of them has turned aside; They have together become corrupt; There is none who does good, No, not one.”
‭‭Psalms‬ ‭53:2-3‬.  <— that would also include Jotham.  Obedience doesn’t indicate a sinless person.